# DNS : How can I get the domain extension 'ai'

Tags: dns

I was browsing the web to find out if I can I have my own custom extension. Turns out it's a long process, but can I have these extensions : `.ai` (or) `.java` (or) `.py` for my website?

Please explain where and for how much can I buy any of the above mentioned extension.

Refer : https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db

Answer (score 1):

To get a domain under the `.ai` just need to find a register that support if, for example: https://www.namecheap.com/domains/registration/results.aspx?domain=foo.ai

To register a new TLD you could check these guidelines/faq, here are some links

- https://newgtlds.icann.org/en/applicants/global-support/faqs/faqs-en
- https://www.icann.org/news/announcement-2-2008-10-23-en

Comment: Can I buy any domain listed in the link I provided? If it's a country-code, can I still buy and use it?

Comment: @JohnMcIntyreJr. yes read more here https://www.namecheap.com/domains/registration/cctld/ai.aspx, but also there are more domain registrars

Comment: You can not "register a TLD". First the ICANN round is now closed so no new applications possible. That will probably reopen sometime in the future but noone knows when. And if it does it is reserved for organizations, an individual can not buy one.

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick research and:

`.java` is a private TLD owned by Oracle and currently they do not sell domain names with it.

`.py` domain names are not available, but are available in second level domains like `.com.py`, `.net.py` and so on. You can by them from [nic.py](https://www.nic.py/)

`.ai` domains can be registered for a minimum of two years and the price is $68.88/year. Here is more info: [Namecheap](https://www.namecheap.com/domains/registration/cctld/ai/?gclid=CjwKCAjwr-PYBRB8EiwALtjbz7j1xa9ANQktHq-Qac0gZ41pAFQ55q-EMNF868xlLVH5OyuoC0KWzBoCiacQAvD_BwE)

Comment: What about .sh? It's available in namecheap, but it's listed as a country-code. Can I still buy it?

Comment: Yes you can (I just read it at nic.sh). You can register most of the ccTLDs. Just some of them have restrictions like citizenship, but it looks like .sh is not like them.

Comment: So its perfectly legal I guess. Thanks much!

Comment: @JohnMcIntyreJr. all TLDs in 2 characters are country code and to get one you need to respect their eligibility requirements. They vary by TLD. Some are completely open, others require you to be a resident of the country, or having its nationality, etc. Any good registrar should be able to explain that to you and show you your options.

Answer (score -1):

Getting the .AI domain through their main registrar can be a tedious process, so I would rather recommend Namecheap, Temok or EuroDns as they will handle the registration faster and save you time. For more detailed information check [AI-domain-FAQ](https://www.domsite.io/ai-domain-faqs/).

Lanexbg already gave enough information about .java and .py and I have nothing to add there.